# How to use a randomly generated string as primary key in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I want to store data about passengers/guests, who book together, with a common reference number consisting of 6 alphanumeric characters. The primary key in the table would have to be (ref_number, number_of_guest) together (e.g. (ASDFJK; 1) refers to guest #1 within the reservation, (ASDFJK; 2) refers to guest #2 within the reservation).
What I want is to create this reference number with a `BEFORE INSERT ON` trigger like `SET NEW.ref = randomlyGeneratedString`, but was sad to see that MySQL has only row level statements, therefore I can only add n different reference numbers to all people within the same reservation, but that just makes no sense.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why does your reference number need to be 6 alphanumeric characters?

Comment: Ideally, you'd have one row in a booking table for the booking itself (and that table would contain the reference number); and separate table for the  passengers/guests, that references the booking.

Comment: Let's suppose that I create a row in a table with that randomly generated reference, but how do I link that to the guests then? So if I have 3 guests in one reservation, I add 3 rows to the `guest` table, but how do I insert the reference number into the records of each of them? Again, the reference is create with a trigger `generate_reference BEFORE INSERT ON reservations`. I can solve the problem by simply generating the reference number in the reservation system and the website, but would prefer to do it within the database. It's such a shame that MySQL lacks statement level triggers...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you need a `primary key`, as usual `primary key` as auto increase,so you can add a field save,then you can do everything.